# Setting the selected option in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I can get this far

```
string selectedOption = ViewBag.SelectedOption;

<select id="SelectedYear" name="SelectedYear">       
    <option value="2010">2010</option>//if(selectedOption == 2010)...meh...
    <option value="2011">2011</option>             
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
```

And I know I can store `SelectedOption` in a `div` and set the selected option with jQuery in a concise way after `$(document).ready`.

Is there a concise method to accomplish the task with straight up MVC3/razor?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like:

```
int selectedOption = ViewBag.SelectedOption;

<select id="SelectedYear" name="SelectedYear">       
    <option value="2010" @(selectedOption == 2010 ? "selected" : "")>2010</option>
    <option value="2011" @(selectedOption == 2011 ? "selected" : "")>2011</option>             
    <option value="2012" @(selectedOption == 2012 ? "selected" : "")>2012</option>
    <option value="2013" @(selectedOption == 2013 ? "selected" : "")>2013</option>
</select>
```

That being said, this is the kind of stuff [HtmlHelper.DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492738.aspx) is for.

Have your logic inside the controller and just pass an *IEnumerable* through *ViewBag*. At that point you just have to call the helper within the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("optionName", ViewBag.MyOptionsList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

Comment: The condition should be on the Selected attribute not its value: <option value="2010" @(selectedOption == 2010 ? "selected" : "")>2010</option>

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, but Amr Elgarhy's solution did. The accepted answer ends up putting selected="" in the markup, which (at least in IE) ends up selecting the option box anyway.

Comment: This code does not work correctly. Amr Elgarhy has it right though.  This code puts attributes on all of the options as selected="" (and since value is ignored even stated by Joao) they all are treated as selected and the last one in the list shows up on the dropdown). It's whether the attribute exists on the option that makes the code work correctly across browsers. So disregard the post and use the code in the first comment and you'll have better luck.

Comment: Try <option value="2010" @(selectedOption == 2010 ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")>2010</option>

Comment: I have enough rep to edit the answer and fix it according to comments by @AmrElgarhy ! :)

Answer (score 18):

`TagHelper` doesn't support C# code in its tag area.

However you can turn an `option` element into a regular html tag using the `!` character.

For example:

```
<!option @(ViewBag.CurrrentPage == x ? "selected" : "")>@x<!/option>
```

Comment: Didn't know about the ! to deactivate the tag area. Very useful, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

```
int selectedOption = ViewBag.SelectedOption;


<select id="SelectedYear" name="SelectedYear"> 

<option value="2010" @if(selectedOption == 2010){<text>selected="selected"</text>}>2010</option>

...

</select>
```

Comment: The html output ends up being selected="selected", anyone have any luck just getting razor to output just the word selected?

Answer (score 3):

The method, answered in the correct question is not working for now, it's better to use the next example:

```
<option value="someValie" @(ViewBag.someVariable == "someValue" ? "selected" : String.Empty)>...</option>
```