# How do I set attribute on cshtml (razor)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to set the "selected" option based on my back end data. Here is a sample of my code...

```
<select id="listName" name="listName">
    <option>Select Name</option>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.NameList as Dictionary<string, string>)
        {                
            //worked in MVC2, not with razor
            <option value= '@item.Key' @if (TempData["name"].ToString() == item.Key) { selected = "&quot;selected&quot;"); }>@item.Value - @item.Key</option> 

            string nameSelect = TempData["name"].ToString() == item.Key ? "selected" : "";
            <option value= '@item.Key' selected= '@nameSelect'>@item.Value - @item.Key</option>                           
        }
</select>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Erm, what is this? How about Html.DropDownListFor? How about view models?

Comment: See this [related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7693791/175679).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this?

Oh, Hell yeah. Using view models of course. So let's define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller action which will populate this view model from your data source:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();

    // preselect an item with Value=2
    model.SelectedValue = "2"; 

    // this could of course come from a database or something
    model.Values = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

and finally a corresponding strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
....


@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values, "Select")
```

Now since you showed some dictionary in your question, we could assume that yo ualready have this dictionary. In your example you've stuffed it in ViewBag (which is wrong) but you could bind it to the view model:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> values = ......

    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.SelectedValue = (string)TempData["name"]; 
    model.Values = values.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.Key,
        Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.Key, x.Value)
    });

    return View(model);
}
```

That's ASP.NET MVC: strong typing, view models, no ViewBag.

Comment: my frontend developers, who code only html, find it is tough if we code like this

Comment: Do your frontend developers know CSS? If they do (which they should if they are calling themselves frontend developers) then simply assign a CSS class to the dropdown: `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values, "Select", new { @class = "values" })` and then give your frontend developers the .value class. It is an absolute **crime** to code ASP.NET MVC views the way you do. So if you want to do ASP.NET MVC the right way, you should really consider using view models. Otherwise you will suffer a lot. This code is an absolute maintenance nightmare.

Comment: they don't know `@Html.DropDownListFor` has the overload and the way `new { @class = "values" }` is somewhat far from html. Yeah, you're right, I was thinking about this nightmare and didn't find a perfect solution that the frontend developer doesn't need to learn the additional C# grammar

Comment: You should really distinguish between the different roles: a web designer (who deals with CSS and cares only about the final markup) and fronend developer who should know the technology being used. The technology being used in your case is called Razor. If your frontend developer doesn't know Razor, then please don't call him a frontend developer and hire a developer that understands the underlying technology. I am really saying this for your own/company's good. Of course you could continue writing horrible spaghetti code but this will cost enormously in terms of maintenance.

Comment: They were both good answers for what I was doing, but as a rookie developer I am trying to get clean with my code. Thanks to both @allentranks and Darin Dimitrov for the insight.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov thanks Darin!I totally agree with you. The razor engine in asp.net mvc 4 is trying to reduce spaghetti codes in grammar level. I think it is of importance for frontend developers. Razor is on the right way. http://www.beletsky.net/2012/04/new-in-aspnet-mvc4-razor-changes.html

Comment: You could of course write your own extensions that hide the complex Razor syntax :).. Then your designers can just use your custom extensions.

Answer (score 2):

except `@Html.DropDownListFor`, you may code like this:

```
<option value= '@item.Key' @(TempData["name"].ToString() == item.Key ? "selected" : "")>@item.Value - @item.Key</option>
```

BTW, I don't like @Html.DropDownListFor ..

Comment: They were both good answers for what I was doing, but as a rookie developer I am trying to get clean with my code. Thanks to both allentranks and @Dimitrov for the insight.