# Drop down item not being selected by default in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, drop-down-menu

I have the following code written in Razor view in MVC in C#. I want to select one of the item based on value but it is not working. I confirmed that the variable `Facilities` contain value `Un-Funded` but it doesn't select this item.

```
<select id="facilities" class="form-control" style="width:200px;">
<option @{ if (Facilities == "Funded") { Response.Write(" selected "); } }>Funded</option>
<option @{ if (Facilities == "Un-Funded") { Response.Write(" selected "); } }>Un-Funded</option>
</select>
```

Here's screenshot of how HTML looks like. Notice it is not printing `selected` for any of the option.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `Response.Write` which doesn't work in Razor view. Using `@Html.Raw("some string")` fixed the issue. So the code will look like this:

```
@{ if(Facilities == "Funded") { @Html.Raw("selected='selected'") } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use js,so that if you have many options,you don't need to check on each option:

```
   <select id="facilities" class="form-control" style="width:200px;">
        <option value="Funded">Funded</option>
        <option value="Un-Funded">Un-Funded</option>
    </select>
<script>
            $(function () {
                $("#facilities").val("@Facilities");
                //Or you can use $("#facilities").val(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Facilities)));
            })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

With MVC 5 you can use this method `@:` to insert your selected:

```
<select id="facilities" class="form-control" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="Funded" @{ if (Facilities == "Funded") { @: selected="selected"
            }}>
        Funded
    </option>
    <option value="Un-Funded" @{ if (Facilities == "Un-Funded") { @: selected="selected"
            }}>
        Un-Funded
    </option>
</select>
```

for older version you can check this link :
[setting-the-selected-option-in-mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693083/setting-the-selected-option-in-mvc3)

Comment: This solution I tested it and work, Is it possible to have the reason of downvote and also a better answer not just a downvote ?